# 13.10 installation does not complete

Tags: installation, 13.10

I'm trying to install 13.10 on a HP dv6 laptop from a dvd. I boot from the dvd, select install Ubuntu, select install inside windows 7, then connect to internet so it can download updates, then i click continue and it reboots and I'm back booting from the dvd again, and it starts all over. At first I thought this was part of the install process, but it just goes through the same menus again. Then I thought maybe if I pop out the disk with it reboots, but then it just boots to windows. :( Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Had the same thing, I had not given enough memory to my virtual machine.

Comment: Never gave an option to specify memory options.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like grub did not install. Or it may be just going directly to windows.

First try booting while holding the SHIFT key. If Grub is installed, and on the correct partition, it will bring up the windows and ubuntu options.

If there is no menu, you may have to reinstall grub.

You can install again manually without going through the Ubuntu install again. [Here is a guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System)

Based on comments below, it doesn't look like Ubuntu installed. Either burn a CD again or make a pen drive to boot to. Bad burns happen more then you'd think.

You can do this from windows, with a 2 (or more) GB flash drive and free software out there.

[Use this with the ISO and USB drive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

You may have to enable USB legacy support to boot to the USB drive. In Ubuntu, you can get to a terminal after you click "Try Ubuntu"

When your data is securely backed up, install again. Make sure that you are putting the bootloader onto the correct partition. `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` will show you where the boot sector currently is.
Make a parition on the drive and make sure that the / (root) is on the partition you create. It is a good idea to create a swap partition as well. A couple gigs is plenty.

[Here is a far more detailed guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Standard_installation)

[And here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Comment: Tried booting and holding shift key. Straight to windows. I really don't think it installed anything before it reboots, I don't even think it has done any partitioning.  Seems like after I tell it I want to install inside windows it should bring up some type of dialog relating to partitions, but it doesn't, only reboots.

Comment: It should definitely bring up partition manager. You may have to install again. Boot to your live CD and look at the `sudo blkid -l` This will bring up all the hard drives and thier partitions. If you do have to partition, it is prudent to back up data first.

Comment: Tried again, same results. It never does any partitioning or copying of files, just reboots.

Comment: I tried the "something else" option just to see where it went and it goes to a screen that shows you want your partition are. I have:/lev/sda, /dev/sda1 ntfs 208mb win7, /dev/sda2 ntfs 621gb win recovery, /dev/sda3 ntfs 18gb win recovery, /dev/sda4 fat32 108mb This is all the partitions the machine came with when new. My newbie instincts tell me there must be somthing wrong with install routine on this dvd. Any thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't really appear that there is an installation there. You can verify by looking in these partitions on sda. These are in /dev on the live cd structure. You would see /bin /boot /cdrom /dev. If there is not, make sure all your data is backed up, and try again. You may have to make a replacement CD. Alternatively, I recommend a change of media.You can use the ISO and a 2 GB or larger pen drive to boot from. See above.

Comment: The partitions on those DV Pavillions can be quite complicated. I think those are the ones with the instant on OS "Splashtop" You need to make sure that the boot loader is loaded onto the proper partition, as well as making a partition on the main area. You definitely should back up before you try again.